# Running Wp Cron jobs automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, cron

I dont know if this is the right section to post this question...

I paid someone to develop a plugin for me. The plugin pulls videos from youtube and posts on wordpress blog based on certain time frequencies set by the plugin user.

But the problem is that the plugin is not posting according to the user's set schedule.

But the programmer who i paid to develop this plugin... he ran away and is not responding me anymore.

So I'd like to get help from you all.

I came to know that the plugin is dependent on wp cron. And I learned that wp cron is only triggered when someone visits your wordpress site.

So on brand new sites, my plugin doesn't do the postings as per the schedule set by the user.

Is there any solution to this problem?

I found a plugin called "Improved Cron". Here's what this plugin does:

"This plugin will visit your site every minute and thereby ensure that your cron jobs run on time. It is mostly intended for people who can't use real cron for some reason."

So its supposed to send fake visits to your wordpress site so that wp cron gets triggered.

But someone this plugin is not working for me.

Is there any alternate solution to this problem?

I'd appreciate any help you guys can provide.

Thanks

Comment: There are free services you could use to ping your website automatically every n minutes / hours... Just do a google search for something like "web cron"